# Is there a simplified way of showing homeomorphism if there are mutual embeddings?

Tags: general-topology

This may be a silly question, but I'll give it a show.

Let $A$ and $B$ be homeomorphic topological spaces s.t. $\exists$ embeddings $f : A \hookrightarrow B$, $g : B \hookrightarrow A$ and $A$ and $B$ are infinite and of the same cardinality.

Is there a way to use the existence of these embeddings to show that the two spaces are homeomorphic, without actually finding a homeomorphism?

Note that I'm requiring that A and B are indeed homeomorphic and am wondering if there is an easier way to show this, using the fact that there are mutual embeddings.

Comment: What do $A,B$ have to do with $X,Y?$

Comment: Ha. Thanks. Hope that helps.

Comment: Why do you assume $A,B$ are homeomorphic to begin with?

Comment: Such embeddings can exist even if $A$ and $B$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: @jhw, because I am looking for an easier way to show that A and B are homeomorphic, if they are, when we know that there are mutual embeddings between A and B.

Answer (score 1):

Such embeddings can exist even if $A$ and $B$ are not homeomorphic, so you can’t hope to use them to find a homeomorphism between $A$ and $B$. For example, $[0,1)$ clearly embeds in $[0,1]$ by the identity map, and $[0,1]$ embeds in $[0,1)$ by the map $x\mapsto\frac{x}2$, but $[0,1]$ is compact, and $[0,1)$ is not, so the spaces are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Indeed. I'm aware of that, but I am saying that if A and B are homeomorphic, is there any way to show this, using the fact that there are mutual embeddings, without directly finding the homeomorphism, or through constructing the homeomorphism using the mutual embeddings?

Comment: @vasshu: It should be clear that the embeddings cannot help you, since they can exist even if $A$ and $B$ are not homeomorphic. You’ve not thought sufficiently about the implications of this fact.

Comment: Just because these embeddings do not in and of themselves imply homeomorphism does not mean that they cannot be helpful.

Comment: @vasshu: It makes it virtually impossible that there is any general result. The embeddings needn’t have anything to do with any homeomorphism between the two spaces.

Comment: I posted almost the same answer here, then deleted it after noticing that homeomorphism between the spaces was assumed as a hypothesis in the question.  My example used $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$, and the mapping The mapping $x\mapsto \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2\left(x-\frac 1 2\right).$ That way I don't need two different mappings: that one function is an embedding of either of these two spaces into the other. $\qquad$